# Kotlin: transform a list of objects into a map of object properties

Tags: function, lambda, kotlin

With the data classes below:

```
data class Photo(val id: String)
data class Album(val id: String, val photos: List<Photo>)
```

I want to be able to turn a list of `Albums` into a Map of `Map<photoId, Set<albumId>>`

for example:

```
val albums = listOf(
    Album("1", listOf(
        Photo("1"),
        Photo("2"),
        Photo("3")
    )),
    Album("2", listOf(
        Photo("1"),
        Photo("2")
    ))
)
```

will transform into:

```
val map = mapOf(
    Pair("1", setOf("1", "2")),
    Pair("2", setOf("1", "2")),
    Pair("3", setOf("1")
)
```

is there a way to do this using the kotlin transformations functions/lambdas? eg, groupBy, flatMap?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cleaner solution

```
val grouped = albums
    .flatMap { album -> album.photos.map { photo -> Pair(photo.id, album.id) } }
    .groupBy( { (photoId, _) -> photoId }, { (_, albumId) -> albumId } )
    .mapValues { it.value.toSet() }
```

And check the correctness

```
val map = mapOf(
    Pair("1", setOf("1", "2")),
    Pair("2", setOf("1", "2")),
    Pair("3", setOf("1"))
)

check(map == grouped) // Success
```

#### A bit of explanation

- With the first `flatMap` we transform the *albums* list (`List<Album>`) in a `List<Pair<String, String>>` (`photo.id` to `album.id`).
- With the `groupBy` we transform the second list into `Map<String, List<String>>` where the key is `photo.id` and grouped by `album..id`
- With `mapValues` we transform the map into `Map<String, Set<String>>`

Comment: Wow, a better solution (clap)! Consider the relation (of photo and album) instead of the object (photo)!

Comment: Thank you for this solution!

Answer (score 1):

A dirty solution:

```
val map = albums.map {
    it.photos.map { it.id } // get all photos in all album
}.flatten() // into a single list (instead of 2-d list)
    .toSet() // remove duplicates
    .associate { photo ->
        photo to albums.filter { it.photos.contains(Photo(photo)) } // for each photo, find its existance in all albums
            .map { it.id }.toSet() // output album ids
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, sorry if this is a silly question but, why is this considered a "dirty" solution?

Comment: @oznecro Because I think there may be a "pure" solution that just take the input `albums` once, and pass them through the whole function, but my solution takes it twice. (However, this maybe a misunderstanding of "pure" in "pure functional programming" by myself.) Besides, using `.apply {}` can avoid this, but I consider if that it is not so clear.